# C++ error in memory allocation

Tags: c

The code below ends with error, compiler points to fprintf(f, szBuffer). Guess this is due to memory allocation. What's wrong with it?

```
int maxl = 1000000;
szBuffer = (char*)malloc(maxl);
if (sock.GetMail(szBuffer, maxl)) 

    {
       FILE* f = fopen("testfile.txt", "wt");
       if (f)
            {
                fprintf(f, szBuffer);
                fclose(f);
                sock.DeleteMail();
            }
        else
            {
                LogEvent("[%s] [ERROR] Cannot create file %s", m_szInstanceName, szFileName);
            }
    }

free(szBuffer);
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and stdio in a question tagged C++

Comment: @KerrekSB - It is not a good choice - simply you end up with programs using both and then a person trying to maintain the code will have to figure out if to use free or delete. As to the use of stdio it removes the type safefly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever make a format string dynamic/accessible/changeable, even if it's trivial.

If (in this case) your text contains potential format markup (like `%s`), you'll cause errors. Also make sure the string is null terminated properly.

Instead use another alternative or add a dummy format string:

```
fprintf(f, "%s", szBuffer);
```

This might actually be the reason for the crash, but without knowing the contents of the mail, we can't say for sure.

Also - as mentioned by Ed in the comments - you shouldn't use `malloc()` and `free()` in a C++ program. Use `new` and `delete` instead, since those will properly call constructors/destructors as necessary (doesn't really matter for an array of `char`, but it's still not really tidy).

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the return value of malloc which can be NULL.

and also you should use fprintf like below

fprintf(f, "%s", szBuffer);

that's because szBuffer may have any format string (like %d, %s etc.) and here you use szBuffer as format string (second parameter).